# Как вывести результат через пробел

Tags: java

Задача: перевернуть строку.

Проблема: пытаюсь вывести через пробел `reversed` (перевёрнутый массив char'ов), а он пишется в консоли вот так: `[C@6dbb137d [C@3c9d0b9d [C@43301423 [C@2f112965 [C@1a04f701 [C@4e91d63f [C@d4342c2 [C@2bbf180e [C@163e4e87`

Если оставить просто `System.out.print(reversed);`, то всё в одно строку получается. Без пробелов.

Код:

```
public class Kata {
    @Test
    public void main() {
        assertEquals("ehT kciuq nworb xof spmuj revo eht yzal .god", Kata.reverseWords("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."));
        //assertEquals("elppa", Kata.reverseWords("apple"));
        //assertEquals("a b c d", Kata.reverseWords("a b c d"));
        //assertEquals("elbuod  decaps  sdrow", Kata.reverseWords("double  spaced  words"));
    }

    public static String reverseWords(final String original) {
        char[] temp = null;
        String[] words = original.split("\\s");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        temp = words[i].toCharArray();
        char[] reversed = new StringBuilder(new String(temp)).reverse().toString().toCharArray();
        System.out.print(reversed + " ");
        }
        return "";
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем тут "char[] reversed = new StringBuilder(....toCharArray();" преобразовывать опять к массиву, можно же получить перевернутую строку и к ней добавить пробел, а затем следующую перевернутую строку. И в самом конце почему-то идет возврат пустой строки "return "";"

```
public static String reverseWords(final String original) {
    char[] temp = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String[] words = original.split("\\s");
    if (words.length == 0) {return original;}
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        temp = words[i].toCharArray();
        sb.append(new StringBuilder(new String(temp)).reverse());
        sb.append(" ");
        System.out.print(sb);
    }
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Ваш код работает, но такую ошибку выдает при проверке: ` index -1,length 0`. Не подскажете с чем может быть связано?

Comment: Нужно добавить проверку на длину строки, если строка пустая то получаем не корректный индекс.

Comment: Наподобие такого? Просто он всё равно не проходит, также пытался null подставить: `if (original == "") {
       return "";
      }`

Comment: Строки нужно сравнивать через equals.
if (original == null || "".equals(original)) {return original;}

Comment: Еще если в данный метод передать строку состоящую из одних пробелов, будет ошибка, поскольку split попытается разбить её на массив строк, но поскольку кроме пробелов там ничего нет, то массив будет пустой

Comment: Я сейчас прошёлся отладчиком, кидаю строку, состоящую из пробелов и он идёт дальше, значит нужно проверку делать на пробелы.

Comment: я добавил после split

Answer (score 0):

Вот новый и более легкий вариант:

```
public class Main
{
  public static String reverseWords(final String original)
  { 
    String[] array = original.split(" ");

    if(array.length == 0) 
        return original;

    int i = 0;
    for(String string : array){
        array[i] = new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
        i++;
    }
    return String.join(" ",array);
  }
}
```